# How can I output a number as a string of bits in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, binary, base-conversion

In C#, how can I output a number as binary to the console? For example, if I have a uint with the value of 20, how can I print to the console: 00010100 (which is 20 in binary)?

Answer (score 9):

Convert.ToString (myValue, 2);

Answer (score 8):

With padding to make the value a byte:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(number, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int x = 3;
string binaryString = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
Console.WriteLine(binaryString);
```

Console will display 11.

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(20, 2));
```